# Way to determine number of elements in array when number is smaller than initialized index?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array initialized to 17 that is storing a certain number of elements. The issue is that when I try to find the size using the sizeof() method or a loop and counter for each element, I get 17, but that is not the number of elements stored in the array, just the size. Does anyone know how to find the actual number of elements in an array, not just its initialized size?

The code I have tried so far:

Method 1:

```
int arr[17];
//after reading in the data from the file
cout << sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])<< endl;
//this just prints 17
```

Method 2:

```
int arr[17]
int counter = 0;
for (int i: arr)
{
 counter++;
}
cout << counter << endl;
//just prints 17
```

Comment: No way of doing that. The number of elements of an array is always the number you created it with. Use a std::vector.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to use objects, you can keep track of how many elements you've added

Comment: You can initialize the array with all zeroes. Then, running through the code with a loop, you can check which elements are not initialized to zero. This means, however, that you cannot store a zero in that array as that will look like an uninitialized element. Just my 2 bits here.

Comment: @ABusy Hey, why use zero? Why not use 42, or -3?

Comment: @NeilButterworth I guess you can use any value that you don't intend to use actually in the array. Zero just popped to my mind, so I gave it as an example.

Comment: @ABusy If you were going to use this approach, which is a very bad one, you should use a distinguished value that is very unlikely to crop up. Zero is very likely to crop up, so something like `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` would be at least marginally better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof()` is evaluated at compile-time, not at runtime.  Taking the size of a fixed array will be a constant value, regardless of how many values you store in it.

You have three options:

1. define a sentry value that will never appear in the actual data, pre-fill the array with that value, and then count the number of elements that do not equal that value:

   ```
   #include <algorithm>

   bool isNotSentry(int value) { return (value != -1); }

   ...

   int arr[17];
   std::fill(arr, arr+17, -1);

   ...

   //when adding a value to the array...
   arr[index] = ...;

   ...

   //after reading in the values from the file
   int count = std::count_if(arr, arr+17, isNotSentry);
   std::cout << count << std::endl;
   ```

   Or, if using C++11 or later:

   ```
   #include <array>

   std::array<int, 17> arr;
   arr.fill(-1);

   ...

   //when adding a value to the array...
   arr[index] = ...;

   ...

   //after reading in the values from the file
   int count = std::count_if(arr.cbegin(), arr.cend(), [](const int value){ return (value != -1); });
   std::cout << count << std::endl;
   ```
2. manually keep track of how many values you put in the array:

   ```
   int arr[17];
   int count = 0;

   ...

   //when adding a value to the array...
   arr[count++] = ...;

   ...

   //after reading in the values from the file
   std::cout << count << endl;
   ```
3. The above approaches assume the data will never be more than 17 values max.  But if you don't know up front how many values may actually be present, then simply don't use a fixed length array to begin with.  Use a `std::vector` instead, which resizes itself dynamically as needed:

   ```
   #include <vector>

   std::vector<int> arr;
   arr.reserve(17); // <-- optional

   ...

   //when adding a value to the vector...
   arr.push_back(...);

   ...

   //after reading in the values from the file
   std::cout << arr.size() << std::endl;
   ```